# How to sort and display text files content newest at top from a root folder

Tags: php

Cannot effectively sort a batch of text files and content within and display newest to old.

I have tried natsort ($directory);

```
<?php
$directory = "feeds/";
$dir = opendir($directory);
while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
    $filename = $directory . $file;
    $type = filetype($filename);
    if ($type == 'file') {
        $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
        $items = explode('\n', $contents);
        echo '<table width="100%" border="1" 
        cellpadding="4" bgcolor="#fff" id="rcorners">';
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            echo"<tr><td id='rcorners'>".nl2br
            ($item)."</td></tr>\n";

        }
        echo '</table>';
    }
}
closedir($dir);
?>
```

There are no errors just do not sort from newest to oldest.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: if you use `file( $filename )` it will create an array of lines which you can sort